# UNIX remove characters from variable

Tags: linux, unix, sed, sh

I want to remove the last 4 charachters from an input string and then use it in a sed command. But i can't get it to work properly

newversion is an input parameter and it is set to: 5.5.5-dev.
I want to remove -dev from the input parameter.

What i have tried:

```
version=${$newversion::-4}
sed -i "s|\(<<some name i defined>>/$imagename:\)\([^\n]*\)|\1$version|" docker-compose.yml
```

The error:

Bad substitution

Comment: It should be `version=${newversion::-4}`. (Note that you used an additional `$`)

Comment: newversion gets injected from a Jenkins build. so $newversion is a variable i use. I should use $ in that case correct?

Comment: Not when used in a [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: `$newversion` is simply an abbreviation for `${newversion}` which you can use if no other parameter substitution operator appears inside the braces.

Answer (score 8):

`sed` is overkill for this problem. To remove `-dev` from the end of a string in any POSIX shell, use

```
version=${newversion%-dev}
```

or more generally

```
version=${newversion%-???}  # Remove the final - and the next 3 characters
```

or even

```
version=${newversion%-*}  # Remove the final - and anything after it.
```

---

If you were using `bash` (which you do not appear to be), your first attempt was close; you simply have an extra `$`. It should be

```
version=${newversion::-4}
```

although a negative value in that position requires `bash` 4. In `bash` 3, you need to compute the value using the length of the string:

```
version=${newversion::${#newversion}-4}
```

Comment: Upvoted; but maybe emphasize the POSIX alternative more clearly, as the OP seems to be using something else than Bash.  Generally, to remove four characters from the end, you could use `${newversion%????}`

Comment: @chepner Basically you are right. But it looks like the `sed` command in the question is used to change a file, not for changing the version number.

Answer (score 2):

If $newversion contains "5.5.5-dev".
i.e `newversion="5.5.5-dev"`

Why don't you try sed to remove -dev.

```
version=`echo $newversion | sed "s/-dev//g"`
```

or if you are using `bash`

```
version=`sed "s/-dev//g"<<<$newversion`
```

Comment: version=`echo $newversion | sed "s/-dev//g"` almost seems to do the trick. The only error i get is this: sed: -e expression #1, char 91: unknown option to `s'. The <<< method isn't compatible with sh

Comment: Sorry I didnot mention, If you are using bash you can go with "<<<"(2nd)one. Else go with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
version="$(echo $newversion | sed 's/-dev//g')"
sed -i "s|\(<<some name i defined>>/$imagename:\)\([^\n]*\)|\1$version|" docker-compose.yml
```

Turned out we needed to wrap it in a method call `$()` this was the solution. With help from Sudheesh shetty

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept one of the answers here instead of posting a duplicate answer.  Thanks.